# Button won't initialize in onClickListener

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

I am trying to add a `Button` dynamically through an `OnClickListener`. But I keep getting an error in the line

```
Button myButton = new Button(this);
```

The error says

```
The constructor Button(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined
```

So how am I supposed to create this `Button` if it won't let me initialize it? Is there a better way I should set up this `OnClickListener`?

```
   button_test.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View view)
                    {

                            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_bttn_words);
                            LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                            Button myButton = new Button(this); //error
                            myButton.setText("Add Me");

                            ll.addView(myButton, lp);    
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
Button myButton = new Button(this);
```

to

```
Button myButton = new Button(view.getContext());
```

Here, `this` refers to the `OnClickListener` hence the error message. What you want is the `Activity Context` which the `view`s (the param in `onClick()`) `Context` will return.

[From the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext()) `getContext()`

> Returns the context the view is running in, through which it can access the current theme, resources, etc.

Comment: thanks. can you explain what the view.getContext() does? Or how it works with the button